# Does the order of command line options matter in Perl?

Tags: perl, options

The following command works as expected:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if /install\(TARGETS (.*) RUNTIME DESTINATION bin\)/' CMakeLists.txt
```

This one works as well:

```
perl -nle 'print $1 if /install\(TARGETS (.*) RUNTIME DESTINATION bin\)/' CMakeLists.txt
```

However, this one errors out:

```
perl -nel 'print $1 if /install\(TARGETS (.*) RUNTIME DESTINATION bin\)/' CMakeLists.txt
```

The error message is:

> Can't open print $1 if /install(TARGETS (.*) RUNTIME DESTINATION
>   bin)/: No such file or directory.

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 6):

The `-e` option takes an argument, a string that will be evaluated as Perl code.  When you use `perl -lne '...'` and `perl -nle '...'` this works as intended as the ordering of the options is not important (in this case).

However, when you use `perl -nel '...'`, you say "evaluate the string `l` as Perl code, and use `'...'` as the name of a file to be read by that code", which makes little sense (this is why you get that strange looking "No such file or directory" error).

So, no, the order of the options is not important (here), but if you move the `-e` option around, you have to move the option-argument, the Perl code, with it, so that the Perl code always comes directly after that option.

So, if you want to put the `-e` option first, for example, use

```
perl -e '...' -ln
```

---

The order of the options to `perl` is important if you mix options like `-p` and `-n` on the same command line.  A `-p` option will be overridden by a later `-n` option and vice versa, so `perl -np` is the same as `perl -p` while `perl -pn` is the same as `perl -n`.  This is documented in the `perlrun` manual (see `man perlrun` or `perldoc perlrun`).

Comment: +1. it's worth noting that this is true for **all** commands with options that take arguments - the option's arg must immediately follow the option.     The only almost-exception I can think of is when running `tar` with the "traditional" style options (e.g. `tar cfz filename.tar.gz` is allowed, but `tar -c -f -z filename.tar.gz` or `tar -cfz` are not because `-f` requires a filename arg....and that's an extreme case for backwards compatibility going back several decades).

Answer (score 3):

From [the `perlrun` manpage](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html):

```
perl ... [ [-e|-E] 'command' ] ...
```

Whatever follows the `-e` option is treated by perl as a command. With `-nel`, `l` is the command for `-e`. `print $1 if /install\(TARGETS (.*) RUNTIME DESTINATION bin\)/` is the first non-option argument, and it becomes the input file, which perl tries to open and fails.

Compare with, say:

```
~ echo  foo | perl -neprint
foo
```